# A selection of objects (with replacement) using combination formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Consider an example where a pack contains 4 blue, 2 red, and 3 black pens. If a pen is drawn at random from the pack, replaced, and the process repeated 2 more times, what is the probability of drawing 2 blue pens and 1 black pen?

Now I am aware that a every single draw is an independent event and so we can use the multiplication rule of probability.
$$\text{Pr(drawing a blue pen)} = \frac{4}{9}$$
$$\text{Pr(drawing a black pen)} = \frac{3}{9}$$

$$\text{Pr(drawing a blue pen on first draw AND drawing a blue pen on the second draw AND drawing a black pen on the third draw)} = \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{9}$$

2 blue pens and 1 black pen can be arranged in $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways so the total probability is $3\cdot\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{9}$.

My question is whether this can be done using just the combination formula?

I learned that you can select $r$ objects out of $n$ with replacement using $${n+r-1 \choose r}.$$

So we can select 2 blue balls out of 4 in ${4+2-1 \choose 2}$ ways and 1 black ball out of 3 using ${3 \choose 1}$ ways. We can choose 3 balls out of a total of 9 (with replacement) in ${9+3-1 \choose 3}$ ways.

According to me the probability using the combination formula should be
$$\frac {{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}}{11 \choose 3}.$$ But this is not the same as what I got using the multiplication rule.

I would be really thankful if someone could guide me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you wrongfully assume that each of the $\binom{11}{3}$ combinations are equally likely.

Getting the combination of $\text{black}_1,\text{black}_1, \text{black}_1$ has a probability of occurring with $\frac{1}{9^3}$ but getting the combination of, say, $\text{black}_1, \text{black}_1, \text{blue}_1$ is not the same, but rather $\frac{3}{9^3}$.

This same mistake of thinking each outcome is equally likely can also be wrongly applied to say that the probability of flipping one head and one tails in two coin flips is $\frac13$. Someone might say "well there are three ways to choose an outcome on two coin flips without order mattering: $HH, HT, TT$. Therefore the probability of one head and one tails is $1/3$"

Perhaps it is easier to see why that method will not work in this more trivial example

Comment: I kind of get your point but at the same time... not really (I don't mean that as an offence; I'm just dumb as a brick). I don't seem to grasp your point about the combinations not being equally likely. Can your elaborate or link me to some kind of website that talks in depth the importance of each of combination have the same likelihood of occurence? I just know one thing about probability: $\text{Pr(event) = number of times the event occured/total number of elements in the sample space}$.

Comment: Let's say you buy one Powerball ticket and one mega million ticket. Now we only have four outcomes here: either they are both losers, the Powerball is a winner, the mega million is a winner, or both are winners. Now we all know the lottery is known for having excessively slim chances of winning. But if we only look at the different outcomes and divide the number of outcomes that are favorable (i.e. winning) by the total number of outcomes, we get that the probability of winning in at least one lottery is $.75$ which is abaurd

Comment: In other words, the combinations with repitition formula is used to find the proportion of outcomes that have two blue pens and one black pen rather than the probability

Comment: You mean the very last formula I wrote in my original post?

Comment: @VineetKumarVerma that "one thing you know about probability" is only true if the outcomes that you are counting in the sample space are equally likely, otherwise it's not true. In virtually all commonly encountered probability models, stars-and-bars outcomes (as in your second formula) are not equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

If we write the generating function that depicts the drawing, we get :

$$  \left( \frac 4 9 b + \frac 3 9 k + \frac 2 9 r \right)^3 $$

The coefficient of $b^2k$ is then

$${3 \choose 2,1,0} \cdot \frac 4 9  \cdot \frac 4 9  \cdot \frac 3 9 $$

We do need the **multinomial** coefficient and the specific probabilities.